# Cannot find a license file in the following locations for atalasoft.dotimage.lic

Tags: c#, winforms, licensing, dotimage

I am getting error for license not found while hitting the winform console application.
Below Code is written in winform application and it is hit by another winform application on button click
I have written code

```
TiffFile tFile = new TiffFile();
TiffDecoder decoder = new TiffDecoder();
TiffEncoder tiff = new TiffEncoder();
tiff.Compression = TiffCompression.Default;
```

Getting this error

> Cannot find a license file in the following locations:'D:\DocProSilentScan\DocProSilentScan\atalasoft.dotimage.lic''C:\Users\sahil.indulkar\AppData\Local\Atalasoft\DotImage 10.6\atalasoft.dotimage.lic'.Stacktrace:    at Atalasoft.Licensing.AtalaLicenseProvider.GetLicense(LicenseContext context, Type type, Object instance, Boolean allowExceptions)at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.ValidateInternalRecursive(LicenseContext context, Type type, Object instance, Boolean allowExceptions, License& license, String& licenseKey)at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.IsValid(Type type, Object instance, License& license)at Atalasoft.Imaging.AtalaImage.c()at Atalasoft.Imaging.AtalaImage.d()at Atalasoft.Imaging.AtalaImage..ctor()at Atalasoft.Imaging.AtalaImage.get_Edition()at Atalasoft.Imaging.Codec.Tiff.TiffFile.a()at Atalasoft.Imaging.Codec.Tiff.TiffFile..ctor(Boolean licCheck)at Atalasoft.Imaging.Codec.Tiff.TiffFile..ctor()at ScanConsoleApplication.Program.UploadFiles() in D:\Sanjay\SVN\DocPro\DocProScan\ScanConsoleApplication\Program.cs:line 249

Please find the attachment for your reference when i added Atalasoft.Dotimage from nuget packages

[image]
[image]
`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sCyo.png)`